# Android: accessing gps function when a button is clicked

Tags: java, android, xml, button, gps

I've made a function which return the gps coordinates and it worked fine so far, but I want it to be launched only when a button is clicked. I've tried to incorporate the gps in a function described by an event launched when the button is clicked, but i get a lot of errors when i do this and i don't have any other ideas on how to solve this.

This is the .java file: (Saver.java)

```
package com.example.lifesaver;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Saver extends Activity {

Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_saver);
b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

/* b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
      localizare();
  }
}); */


 // We use LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations
LocationManager mlocManager =   (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
}

//MyLocationListener class

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
//  private void localizare()
//  {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        String Text = "Current location is: " + "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +   "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }
}//}
}
```

and the .xml file(activity)saver.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Saver" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/circle" 
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, i've added this in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
</uses-permission>
```

Comment: what does "a lot of errors" mean? you need to be more specific.

Comment: what are the errors? plese post the logcat so people will have ideas.

Comment: 1." the method localizare() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}" or 2. "the type Saver.MyLocationListener must implement the inherited abstract method LocationListener.onStatusChanged(String,int,Bundle)" or 3."void is an invalid type for the variable onLocationChanged"

Comment: are you getting that error even after commenting that line into code ?  Please remove this line `android:onClick="onClick"` from your .xml an re-run it.

Comment: still having errors... :(

Comment: please read my ansewer below, i provide you the code. a copy paste will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is let the listener works by itsself, but when the location changes, do nothing, and just save the location information in a field.
Then, add the listener to the button. When the user clics the button, in the listener you read that field, and do whatever you need (like the toast in the example). So the last known location is always available in the newLocation field, but is only read when the button is pressed

here is the code:

```
public class Saver extends Activity {

    Button b;

    Location newLocation = null;//add thiss

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saver);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


             //set this listener
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (newLocation != null) {

                    String Text = "Current location is: " + "Latitud = "
                            + newLocation.getLatitude() + "Longitud = "
                            + newLocation.getLongitude();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        // We use LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations
        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                mlocListener);
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

               //save the new location
               newLocation = loc;

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I add a flag "isGpsOn".

```
package com.example.lifesaver;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Saver extends Activity {

Button b;
boolean isGpsOn  = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_saver);
b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

 b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
      isGpsOn = true;
  }
}); 


 // We use LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations
LocationManager mlocManager =   (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
}

//MyLocationListener class

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
//  private void localizare()
//  {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        if (isGpsOn)
        {
            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();
            String Text = "Current location is: " + "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +   "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }
}//}
}
```

Comment: that wont do it, since after the first activation, the onLocationChanged(Location loc) will keep being called every few seconds, and what he wants is to retrieve the the location in the moment he wants.
also, if you dont let the observer work from the begining, probably in the moment you press the botton, it will take a lot the get the first data.